# Meteor user updates are very slow

Tags: javascript, mvvm, meteor, model, prototype

I have a meteor app that allows users to update their skype name, phone number, email address, etc.  To help maintain a consistent code base I have implemented an EJSON type UserModel in a common directory so it can run on the client and server.

`EJSON.addType("UserModel", function fromJSONValue(value) {
    return new UserModel(value);
});`

```
UserModel.prototype = {

constructor: UserModel,

//
// EJSON Ovverrides.
//
valueOf: function() {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this), function(key, value) {
        var dateFields = ["expiration", "createdAt"];
        if(_.contains(dateFields, key) && typeof value === "string") {
            return new Date(value);
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    });
},

typeName: function() {
    return 'UserModel';
},

toJSONValue: function() {
    return this.valueOf();
},

clone: function() {
    return new UserModel(this.valueOf());
},

equals: function(other) {
    if(!(other instanceof UserModel)) {
        return false;
    }
    return this._id === other._id;
},
setPhoneNumbers: function(phoneNumber, queueUpdate)    {
    var modifier = {$set: {
        'profile.phoneNumber': phoneNumber
    }};
    this.profile.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    return this._saveOrQueueUpdate(modifier, queueUpdate);
},

_saveOrQueueUpdate: function(modifier, queueUpdate) {
    if (!queueUpdate) {
        return Meteor.users.update(this._id, modifier, function(err, res) {
        });
    } else {
        this.pendingUpdates.push(modifier);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I call the `setPhoneNumbers` method on the settings page js file like so.

```
'blur #phonenumber':function(){
    var user = Meteor.user();
    var number = $("#phonenumber").val();
    if(number.length){
        user.setPhoneNumbers(number);
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that whenever I call the `setPhoneNumbers` method, the page takes >500ms to update and locks the entire page.  I looked at the docs and according to [this segment](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/update), client code should never be blocking. The page only locks up when updates happen so I know it has something to do with the UserModel.  Any insight to what could be causing this would be very helpful.  The page is extremely slow and it is unacceptable for a production app.

Comment: Just curious to better understand the flow of logic, why does the `setPhoneNumbers` method return `_saveOrQueueUpdate`?

Comment: Basically, the `setPhoneNumbers` method is taking some time to run.  This might be worth trying.  I learned this while looking at one of [Kadira](http://kadira.io) tutorials: 
https://bulletproofmeteor.com/basics/defer-the-execution/4.

Your wrap the code inside `Meteor.setTimeout()` which will do the work inside the method will not affect method response time.

Comment: _saveOrQueueUpdate is a method which I have not implemented yet.  Essentially it just returns Meteor.users.update({}).  Thank you for the recommendation on the setTimeout().  That is exactly what I was looking for.